# Overwrite TextBoxFor Helper in ASP.NET MVC with HtmlAttributes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Am Trying to use custom TextBoxFor in ASP.NET MVC 3 to change some existing attributes.

While rendering,

```
@Html.MYTextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "textfield", @tabindex = "1", @maxlength = "50", @size = "30" })
```

But it ignores the htmlAttributes(tabindex,maxlength,size).

```
public static MvcHtmlString MYTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    string elementName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);               

    MvcHtmlString normal = html.TextBoxFor(expression);
    if (normal != null)
    {
        string newValidator = normal.ToHtmlString();                
        newValidator = newValidator.Replace("data-val-required", "databvalidatormsg");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(newValidator);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you passing the attributes to your code? It will ignore the attributes since you don't pass it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're not using your `htmlAttributes` arg anywhere in the function.

Don't you need something like...

```
MvcHtmlString normal = html.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
```

Also, you don't need the `@` char infront of the tabindex, maxlength and size attributes.